# Why is not runing this code on my page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```js
var autocomplete = {};
var autocompletesWraps = ['test', 'test2'];

var test_form = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};
var test2_form = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {

  $.each(autocompletesWraps, function(index, name) {

    if ($('#' + name).length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    autocomplete[name] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('#' + name + ' .autocomplete')[0], {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[name], 'place_changed', function() {

      var place = autocomplete[name].getPlace();
      var form = eval(name + '_form');

      for (var component in form) {
        $('#' + name + ' .' + component).val('');
        $('#' + name + ' .' + component).attr('disabled', false);
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (typeof form[addressType] !== 'undefined') {
          var val = place.address_components[i][form[addressType]];
          $('#' + name + ' .' + addressType).val(val);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}

#locationField,
#controls {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
}

#autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 99%;
}

.label {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  color: #303030;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #000090;
  background-color: #f0f0ff;
  width: 480px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

table td {
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.field {
  width: 99%;
}

.slimField {
  width: 80px;
}

.wideField {
  width: 200px;
}

#locationField {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">

  <div id="test">

    <input class="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field street_number" disabled="true"></input>
        </td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field route" disabled="true"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field locality" disabled="true"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input>
        </td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field postal_code" disabled="true"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field country" disabled="true"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <br /><br />

  <div id="test2">

    <input class="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field street_number" disabled="true"></input>
        </td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field route" disabled="true"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field locality" disabled="true"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input>
        </td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field postal_code" disabled="true"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field country" disabled="true"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I copied this code on same website and this code run on this website but when I copy this code and paste on my other page run this but this does not run.

Second I am using my api on this /maps/api/js?v=MY API USING.exp&libraries=place
and my Google API =AIzaSyCs2QvVo6pUXt6RDDc25Aqk9lhQIge9Px8
Please tell what can I do on this code

Comment: Any errors in the `console`? It can be because of 1000 reasons..

Comment: tell me how can solved this error

Comment: Can you see error in the `console` what it is?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/nL68hguq/) here. You may have a look. I have done a bit of modification to your code and now it is working !

**JS Code:**

```
$(function() {
var autocomplete = {};
        var autocompletesWraps = ['test', 'test2'];

        var test_form = { street_number: 'short_name', route: 'long_name', locality: 'long_name', administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name', country: 'long_name', postal_code: 'short_name' };
        var test2_form = { street_number: 'short_name', route: 'long_name', locality: 'long_name', administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name', country: 'long_name', postal_code: 'short_name' };

        function initialize() {

            $.each(autocompletesWraps, function(index, name) {

                if($('#'+name).length == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                autocomplete[name] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('#'+name+' .autocomplete')[0], { types: ['geocode'] });

                google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[name], 'place_changed', function() {

                    var place = autocomplete[name].getPlace();
                    var form = eval(name+'_form');

                    for (var component in form) {
                        $('#'+name+' .'+component).val('');
                        $('#'+name+' .'+component).attr('disabled', false);
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                        if (typeof form[addressType] !== 'undefined') {
                          var val = place.address_components[i][form[addressType]];
                          $('#'+name+' .'+addressType).val(val);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }

     initialize();
  });
```

Comment: It seems that his code working too. He just said that the code are not working in **his** website..

Comment: I have already stated in my answer that "I have done a bit of modification to your code". His code has got some problems, so after modification that I have made, the code is working now.

Comment: this is code not work i am using same code when you provide me but this is not work after that i am replace your api but this is not work

Comment: You may take the whole code from my DEMO including the HTML code because I have modified some links realted to google maps API. And after taking my whole code it is still not working, then open up the developer console and look for possible errors. This might help